# What does it mean by saying 'a random variable $\mathit X$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable'?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, filtrations

**This is the definition of "measurability":**

Let $\mathit X$ be a random variable defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$. Let $\mathcal G$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$. If $\sigma(\mathit X) \subseteq \mathcal G$, we say that $\mathit X$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable.

I can understand this definition, but what does it mean that "**a random variable $\mathit X$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable if and only if the information in $\mathcal G$ is sufficient to determine the value of $\mathit X$"**?

**My questions are:**

1. What is the "information" in  $\mathcal G$? As far as I know,  $\mathcal G$ is just a set of subsets of $\Omega$. Thus $\mathcal G$ contains lots of "events". Then, when we say "information", what exactly do we mean？ I can't imagine other information except for the elements of $\mathcal G$.
2. How can the "information" in $\mathcal G$ determine the value of $\mathit X$? Given $\mathcal G$, what we know is just "the elements of $\mathcal G$". How could this "infromation" help us determine the value of $\mathit X$?

**Example:**

This is an example of rolling a die with $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$:

$$\mathit X_1(\omega)=\omega$$

$$\mathit X_2(\omega)=\begin{cases} 1, & \omega\in \{1,3,5\} \\-1, & \omega\in \{2,4,6\}\end{cases}$$

$\mathit X_1$ and $\mathit X_2$ are both random variables. $\mathit X_1$ gives the exact outcome of the roll, and $\mathit X_2$ is a binary variable whose value depends on whether the roll is odd or even.

Let $\mathcal G = \{\emptyset, \Omega, \{1,3,5\}, \{2,4,6\}\}$, then $\mathit X_2$ is measurable w.r.t $\mathcal G$ but $\mathit X_1$ is not measurable w.r.t $\mathcal G$. I know this because I can check that $\sigma(X_2)=\mathcal G$ according to the defination of $\sigma(X_2)$.

*Here are the questions:*

1. What's the information in $\{\emptyset, \Omega, \{1,3,5\}, \{2,4,6\}\}$? What else can we know except for those four elements in $\{\emptyset, \Omega, \{1,3,5\}, \{2,4,6\}\}$?
2. If this is the only 'information' that we can obtain from $\mathcal G$ (i.e., there are four elements in $\mathcal G$, and those elements are $\emptyset$, $\Omega$, $\{1,3,5\}$ and $\{2,4,6\}$), how can we determine what the value of $\mathit X_2$ will be?

Comment: What is your definition of $\sigma$?

Comment: This intuition about 'the information in G' is clarified by thinking about $G$ as being $G = \sigma( Y_1, \ldots, Y_m)$, where the $Y_i$ are measurements that someone is making about some experiment for which $X$ is another possible measurement. If $X \in \sigma(Y_1, \ldots, Y_m)$, you can express the value of $X$ in terms of the values of $Y_i$ (literally there is some measurable function $f$ so that $X = f(Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$)  ) -- hence you can express $X$ in terms of the information in the $Y_i $ which is to say, the information in $G$.

Comment: @DEATH_CUBE_K Hi, $\sigma$-algebra is the subset of $\Omega$ that includes $\Omega$ itself, is closed under complement, and is closed under countable unions. I can understand this concept.

Comment: One common place for this 'information' intuition to come up is if you have a stochastic process of some kind -- say a random walk -- and the information at time $n$ refers to the sigma algebra $F_n$ generated by the first $n$ positions in the random walk. If some random variable is in $F_n$, then you can calculate it based on seeing the first $n$ steps of the walk -- you have enough information -- but if some random variable is not in $F_n$, you cannot calculate it at that time, because you do not have enough information.

Comment: That doesn't explain what $\sigma(X)$ means. What is the definition?

Comment: $\sigma(X_1)$ is the sigma algebra generated by all events of the form $\{X_1 \leq a\}$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: Saying $\sigma(X) \subseteq G$ is the same as saying that $X$ is $G$ measurable, because it is asserting that all events $\{X \leq a \}$ are in $G$.

Comment: @DEATH_CUBE_K It's $\sigma$-algebra generated by random variable $\mathit X_1$.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt Thanks! It seems like  the Doob–Dynkin lemma. I know there is some measurable function f so that $\mathit X=f(\mathit Y)$ if $\mathit X$ is measurable w.r.t $\sigma(\mathit Y)$. But I still can't understand what information is in $\mathcal G$ except for knowing the elements of it.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt and, I read somewhere that "if we know $\mathcal G$, then we can know the value of $\mathit X$". But what we know about $\mathcal G$ when we say we know it?

Comment: "I still can't understand what information is in G except for knowing the elements of it. " -- if you want, you can think about the 'information' in $G$ as observations about which events in $G$ occured in our experiment: We get some example $\omega$ from our probability distribution, and then the information in G is the information of, for each $A \in G$, whether $\omega \in A$ (that is, whether $A$ occurred in the universe/outcome $\omega$).

Comment: @LorenzoNajt It's really intuitive to think about information in $\mathcal G$ like this. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: You're welcome. :-)

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/932553/36150) and the first part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3132370/36150)

Comment: @LorenzoNajt That means, if we know for every event in $\mathcal G$ whether it occurred or not, then we can know $\mathit X(\omega)$ even though we still don't know $\sigma$. Right?

Comment: @saz Thanks for your reference. Actually I searched for this topic and have read these two Q&As. It's very helpful, but I'm still not sure about how to think about information.